# Redirect asynchronous C# prints/strings into python

Tags: c#, python

I am using python 3.7 with python NET on a windows setup.
I have a C# .dll I am reading from, that prints some error prints via interrupts.
When I invoke a C# .dll function via python, it may return the print in some period of time and not during its run.
Is there a way to redirect `stdout` if the prints are a-synchronous?
Or maybe it is possible to constantly monitor the stdout of the C# .dll via a thread?

Comment: The question is unclear and probably uses various terms in the wrong way. For esample, `stdout` is a feature of each process, not any language or libraries. That means the C# code has no `stdout` of its own. Post code that demonstrates the actual problem

Comment: i THINK you mean using Console.WriteLine